Cannot change localization string
I am using the Azure B2C sign up flow. I want to change some strings, but some of the stringsIDs are not accepted:

I can find it in the attribute fields:

But, when trying to update it I get an error.

Anything I can do to actually update it???
Thanks.

Could you inadvertently be using any special characters/characters not allowed? And do you need to encode the string?

No, it should be straight forward. I have a lot of other overrides which work just fine.

Are you using the localisation file?
That string is valid - it's here, but as per the documentation, you need to use "The following IDs are used for a Verification display control with page layout version 2.1.0 or higher."

Yes, I am using the override file generated from other overrides which works just fine. I have also read the link you sent, however, on that page success_verify_code_msg is only mentioned for e-mail. This is for verification code. Does that make a difference?
